# Is there a memory leak in the data.table package in R 3.6.0?

Tags: r, memory-leaks, data.table

in R 3.6.0 (Pre-release) *only* I have a memory leak in the data.table package. This happens on the CRAN version as well as on the GH version.

```
require(data.table)
n <- 2e6
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(n),
                 b=factor(rbinom(n,5,prob=0.5),1:5,letters[1:5]),
                 c=factor(rbinom(n,5,prob=0.5),1:5,letters[1:5]))
dt <- setDT(df)
print(pryr::mem_used())
fff <- function(aref) {
  ff <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    dt2 <- dt[,list(sumA=sum(get(aref))),by=b][,c:=letters[i]]
    dt2
  })
  return(rbindlist(ff))
}
for(i in 1:10) {
  f <- fff("a")
  rm("f")
  gc()
  print(pryr::mem_used())
}
gc()
print(pryr::mem_used())
```

returns (3.6.0 *only*)

```
81.2 MB
81.2 MB
81.2 MB
184 MB
287 MB
390 MB
493 MB
596 MB
699 MB
802 MB
```

any ideas?

Both the call to "get" and the "by" appear to be necessary. The `[,c:=letters[i]] is NOT, but it makes the memory leak appear much faster.

My session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2018-05-10 r74708)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0   pryr_0.1.4       magrittr_1.5     tools_3.6.0     
[5] Rcpp_0.12.16     stringi_1.1.7    codetools_0.2-15 stringr_1.3.0
```

Comment: I assume you are aware of the data.table github page where you can report issues? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues. Something this specific to a dev version of software is more likely to be addressed by the right people if reported in the right place.

Comment: Could still be an R Core issue if changes in the refcount semantics (hello, `ALTREP`) causes this...

Comment: In any event, R 3.6.0 is 11 1/2 months out so ...

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm required to post here before submitting an issue. I agree this one would have been better as just an issue, but I get why they request that with a package that has so many users.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel to submit my package to CRAN it has to pass checks on R-devel (3.6.0 pre-release), so it's a problem right now for me.

Comment: That's a fair point. But what makes you think this is an issue with _your_ package?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm not understanding. I'm importing data.table and when I use it, data.table causes a package I want to submit to fail checks (R eats all the memory on then what happens next is a bit erratic). I can tell this is my problem, because I can delete a data.table line and the package passes checks (but gives bad results). It also works fine as in in R 3.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yay! A reproducible example. We've been struggling for a few weeks in this area. Your example looks extremely useful. Please join us on GitHub.

The current milestone (next release) is 1.11.4 and there are several related issues there. What made you think we didn't want you to raise an issue? Bullet point 3 of the [issue template](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md) I guess. I've now changed those points to be clearer, I hope. You're a package developer having issues at-the-moment with as yet unreleased R 3.6.0 and recently released data.table, so that should be on GitHub.

[image]

Comment: Check out  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2866 I'm marking this as the answer because it is the answer: yup, it is real.

Comment: Many thanks. I've tagged it 1.11.4 and I'll start looking today.

Comment: The short term fix for me (suggested by Luke Tierney) was to put data.table::setDTthreads(1) in my package to prevent what is, apparently a race condition--and not a memory leak.